# Required bean not found when moved to another package when running Spring Boot app with maven

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I've made a project from [this Spring Data example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security). I've moved ItemRepository and EmployeeRepository to another package `persistence`. Now, when I launch the app with `mvn spring-boot:run` it complains that it can't find them.

```
Field employeeRepository in test.Application required a bean of type 'test.persistence.EmployeeRepository' that could not be found.
```

It loads normally if I just run the main application.

Why does this happen?

Comment: @JBNizet It says that _If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation._ Since I'm not specifying any package, it should start from my package `test`, where the main class is. The beans are in `test.persistence`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry I read too fast.

Comment: `mvn clean package` then `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the next 2 annotations need to define where are located all repositories inside your ptoject. Probably you have the old package route and cant find the classes now.

```
//Package where you store all yours repositories
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.your.path.persistence" })

//package where you store all yours Entities
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.your.path.domain" })
```

Comment: `@EnableJpaRepositories` has nothing to do with Spring Boot, it is from the Spring Data JPA project.

Comment: @M.Deinum Right, was EntityScan the one included in sprong-boot packages for autoconfigure.